# modify existing contents of file in c

Tags: c, edit, file-handling

```
int main()
{
    FILE *ft;
    char ch;
    ft=fopen("abc.txt","r+");
    if(ft==NULL)
    {
        printf("can not open target file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        ch=fgetc(ft);
        if(ch==EOF)
        {
            printf("done");
            break;
        }
        if(ch=='i')
        {
            fputc('a',ft);
        }
    }
    fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

As one can see that I want to edit `abc.txt` in such a way that `i` is replaced by `a` in it.
The program works fine but when I open `abc.txt` externally, it seemed to be unedited.
Any possible reason for that?

Why in this case the character after `i` is not replace by `a`, as the answers suggest?

Comment: Try `fflush()`-ing the descriptor maybe...

Comment: fclose(ft) before you return.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`; it has to return every valid `char` value plus a separate value, EOF.  As written, you can't reliably detect EOF.  If `char` is an unsigned type, you'll never find EOF; if `char` is a signed type, you'll misidentify some valid character (often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) as EOF.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Analysis

There are multiple problems:

1. `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`; it has to return every valid `char` value plus a separate value, EOF. As written, you can't reliably detect EOF. If `char` is an unsigned type, you'll never find EOF; if `char` is a signed type, you'll misidentify some valid character (often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) as EOF.
2. If you switch between input and output on a file opened for update mode, you must use a file positioning operation (`fseek()`, `rewind()`, nominally `fsetpos()`) between reading and writing; and you must use a positioning operation or `fflush()` between writing and reading.
3. It is a good idea to close what you open (now fixed in the code).
4. If your writes worked, you'd overwrite the character after the `i` with `a`.

### Synthesis

These changes lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *ft;
    char const *name = "abc.txt";
    int ch;
    ft = fopen(name, "r+");
    if (ft == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open target file %s\n", name);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(ft)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == 'i')
        {
            fseek(ft, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc('a',ft);
            fseek(ft, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

There is room for more error checking.

### Exegesis

#### Input followed by output requires seeks

The `fseek(ft, 0, SEEK_CUR);` statement is required by the C standard.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function
>
> ¶7 When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
>   above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
>   associated stream. *However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
>   `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-
>   file.* Opening (or creating) a text file with update mode may instead open (or create) a
>   binary stream in some implementations.

(Emphasis added.)

#### `fgetc()` returns an `int`

Quotes from ISO/IEC 9899:2011, the current C standard.

> **§7.21 Input/output `<stdio.h>`**
>
> **§7.21.1 Introduction**
>
> `EOF` which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value, that
>   is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a
>   stream;
>
> **§7.21.7.1 The `fgetc` function**
>
> `int fgetc(FILE *stream);`
>
> ¶2 If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a
>   next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` and advances the associated file position indicator for the
>   stream (if defined).
>
> **Returns**
>
> ¶3 If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns EOF. Otherwise, the
>   `fgetc` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream.
>   If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function
>   returns EOF.<sup>289)</sup>
>
> <sup>289)</sup> An end-of-file and a read error can be distinguished by use of the `feof` and `ferror` functions.

So, `EOF` is a negative integer (conventionally it is -1, but the standard does not require that).  The `fgetc()` function either returns EOF or the value of the character as an `unsigned char` (in the range 0..UCHAR_MAX, usually 0..255).

> **§6.2.5 Types**
>
> ¶3 An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of the basic
>   execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a
>   `char` object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative. If any other character is stored in
>   a `char` object, the resulting value is implementation-defined but shall be within the range
>   of values that can be represented in that type.
>
> ¶5 An object declared as type `signed char` occupies the same amount of storage as a
>   ‘‘plain’’ `char` object.
>
> §6 For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned
>   integer type (designated with the keyword `unsigned`) that uses the same amount of
>   storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements.
>
> §15 The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called
>   the character types. The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.<sup>45)</sup>
>
> <sup>45)</sup> `CHAR_MIN`, defined in `<limits.h>`, will have one of the values `0` or `SCHAR_MIN`, and this can be
>   used to distinguish the two options. Irrespective of the choice made, `char` is a separate type from the
>   other two and is not compatible with either.

This justifies my assertion that plain `char` can be a signed or an unsigned type.

Now consider:

```
char c = fgetc(fp);
if (c == EOF)
   …
```

Suppose `fgetc()` returns EOF, and plain `char` is an unsigned (8-bit) type, and EOF is `-1`.  The assignment puts the value 0xFF into `c`, which is a positive integer.  When the comparison is made, `c` is promoted to an `int` (and hence to the value 255), and 255 is not negative, so the comparison fails.

Conversely, suppose that plain `char` is a signed (8-bit) type and the character set is ISO 8859-15. If `fgetc()` returns ÿ, the value assigned will be the bit pattern 0b11111111, which is the same as `-1`, so in the comparison, `c` will be converted to `-1` and the comparison `c == EOF` will return true even though a valid character was read.

You can tweak the details, but the basic argument remains valid while `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`.  There are DSP chips where that doesn't apply; you have to rethink the rules.  Even so, the basic point remains; `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

If your data is truly ASCII (7-bit data), then all characters are in the range 0..127 and you won't run into the misinterpretation of ÿ problem.  However, if your `char` type is unsigned, you still have the 'cannot detect EOF' problem, so your program will run for a long time.  If you need to consider portability, you will take this into account.  These are the professional grade issues that you need to handle as a C programmer.  You can kludge your way to programs that work on your system for your data relatively easily and without taking all these nuances into account.  But your program won't work on other people's systems.

Comment: `fseek(ft, 0, SEEK_CUR);` This line is doing nothing and isn't needed.

Comment: @zee: I don't know how to explain it better.  Plain `char` can be a signed type or an unsigned type.  Whichever it is, using `char c = fgetc(fp);` is wrong — you must read the result into an `int`.  (There might be exceptions for oddball systems where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`, but not otherwise.)

Comment: @OregonTrail: _au contraire_.  The C standard requires a positioning operation between a read and a write operation on an update stream, or between a write and a read.  This is a positioning operation between a write and a read.  It is **not** a no-op; it places the stream into a mode which allows the next `fgetc()` to work correctly, reliably, across platforms, as required by the C standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : but I think that even if I declare it as `char` then also it stores its ascii code. so what makes difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler K&R specifies only three modes for opening a file - `"r"`, `"w"`, `"a"` with `"b"` appended sometimes to distinguish between text and binary files (page 160). What is `"r+"` mode and was it added later to the `C` standard? Are there `"w+"` and `"a+"` modes also?

Comment: @ajay : yes there are modes `"w+"` and `"a+"`. `"w+"` :- create a text file for read/write. `"a+"` :- append or create a text file for read/write

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting, I'll start doing that if you can point me to the relevant documentation. I began searching but I can't find it.

Comment: @zee `EOF` is a value such that for any character ch, `EOF == ch` is always false. Therefore to store the value of `EOF` you should use an `int` type variable, not a `char` type because depending on whether `char` type is signed or unsigned, the value of `EOF` maybe interpreted as that of a character.

Comment: @OregonTrail Check [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) out, it says 'Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file.'

Comment: @ajay: 7th Edition Unix only had `"r"`, `"w"`, and `"a"` modes in 1979.  However, the first edition of the C standard (1989) had the extended modes (the `b` modifier, and the `+` modes), and I think the `+` modes were available even earlier.

Comment: @ajay : you mean to say that `EOF` could be a value out of range of `char`

Comment: @zee `EOF` is not a character! Therefore, it has to be *out of range* of `char`. It's a value to signal that no more characters can be read from a stream.

Comment: @ajay : so `EOF` could also be out of range of int. Then what?

Comment: @zee The value of `EOF` is an integer (commonly -1). The only requirement is it just has to be unequal to any valid character code. It cannot be out of range of `int` type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : `This is a positioning operation between a write and a read. It is not a no-op; it places the stream into a mode which allows the next fgetc() to work correctly, reliably, across platforms, as required by the C standard`. How `fseek(ft, 0, SEEK_CUR);` allow fgetc() work correctly?

Comment: @ajay : but -1 comes under the range of `char`

Comment: @zee That depends on whether `char` is signed or unsigned type. If `char` is signed type, then EOF will be some int value different from all character codes on the machine. I said `commonly` it's `-1`. It's an implementation detail and you don't have to bother about its actual value. Just have a type different from `char` and big enough to store it. That's all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : in my case, the character after `i`, is also not replaced by `a`. why?

Comment: @zee: In your original code, you were not doing the `fseek()` operations.  If you checked the return value from `fputc()`, you'd probably get an error indication.  See also my (extensive) update and the 'Exegesis' section.  The standard doesn't say how `fseek(ft, 0, SEEK_CUR)` allows `fgetc()` to work correctly; it just says that it must do so.  The how is a problem for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing the 'i' in `abc.txt`, you are changing the next character after 'i'. Try to put `fseek(ft, -1, SEEK_CUR);` before your `fputc('a', ft);`.

After you read a 'i' character, the file position indicator of `ft` will be the character after this 'i', and when you write a character by `fputc()`, this character will be write at the current file position, i.e. the character after 'i'. See [`fseek(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) for further details.

Comment: if I put `fseek(ft, -1, SEEK_CUR); `, the loop turns to be infinite.

Comment: @zee No, it will not.

Comment: oops sorry...that was a other mistake

Comment: in my case, the character after `i`, is also not replaced by `a`. why?

Comment: @zee I tested the code included in your question in a Linux system, it indeed changed all the characters after these 'i' characters in `abc.txt`. How did you test your code? And in which OS?

Comment: it worked for me only when I add `fseek(ft,0,SEEK_CUR);` before and after `fputc(ft)`

Comment: Put the `fseek(ft, 0, SEEK_CUR); fflush(ft);` after your `fputc('a', ft);` and try again.

Comment: why I have to do that. And what `fflush(ft)` do in this case

Comment: @zz Well, I guess this is one of the differences between Windows and Linux, and according to ANSI C, it is what you should do. "For output streams, `fflush()` forces a write of all user-space buffered data for the given output or update stream via the stream's underlying write function." See [`fflush(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush)

Comment: and why I need to do fseek(ft,0,SEEK_CUR);

Comment: @zee: because the standard says you need it, and because it doesn't work when you don't do it.  How many more reasons do you need?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : you got me wrong. The standards are also made according to specific reasons. I want to know why this standard is made? If you know.

Comment: @zee: In general, the more peculiar provisions in the C standard are there because some system or other has difficulty handling things if the provision isn't made. For an extreme example, see the restrictions on how you can use the `setjmp()` macro from `<setjmp.h>`. More nearly topical, there are restrictions on what happens with text files (trailing blanks, final newline) that make it possible for systems to comply with the standard that otherwise could not. In this case, I'm not sure of all the ins and outs, but it makes the implementation easier. Remember there's `ungetc()` to handle too.

Answer (score 0):

After reading 'i' you need to "step back" to write to the correct location.

```
if(ch=='i')
{
    fseek(ft, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    fputc('a',ft);
}
```

Comment: You also need a second `fseek()` operation after the `fputc()` according to the C standard — see my answer for the relevant quotes from the standard.