# need of fseek() in c

Tags: c, file-handling, fseek

Part of Code 1:-

```
while(1)
    {
        ch=fgetc(pt);
        if(c==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(c==' ')
        {
            fputc('z',pt);
        }
    }
```

Part of Code 2:-

```
while(1)
{
    ch=fgetc(pt);
    if(c==EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
    if(c==' ')
    {
        fseek(pt,0,SEEK_CUR);
        fputc('z',pt);
        fseek(pt,0,SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

I want to replace next character after every `space` in a file. That file is pointed by the pointer `pt`.

Both the code shows no error and runs fine, but when I externally opens the `.txt` file, first code did nothing whereas the second code replaces the next character after `space` successfully.

Clearly `fseek(pt,0,SEEK_CUR);` is making the difference.

So I am unable to understand that what it is doing in the second code?

Comment: Are you sure it's fputc('z', ft) and not fputc('z', pt) in the 2nd code?

Comment: @AndyFaizan : oops sorry...My mistake!!!!That was `pt`

Comment: possible duplicate of [modify existing contents of file in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958155/modify-existing-contents-of-file-in-c)

Comment: @leeduhem: Not exactly but the answer there solves the issue.

Comment: @kevingomes: The use of fseek() here - The C standard requires a positioning operation between a read and a write operation on an update stream, or between a write and a read. This is a positioning operation between a write and a read. It is not a no-op; it places the stream into a mode which allows the next fgetc() to work correctly, reliably, across platforms, as required by the C standard

Comment: @AndyFaizan : I also read `Jonathan Leffler` comment, but I am asking what the presence of `fseek(pt,0,SEEK_CUR)` do in this case.

Comment: Doesn't my comment answer this question?

Comment: @AndyFaizan : in your comment you stated what c standard requires. That I also know. What I am asking is that what it is doing?????

Comment: From the comment - "it places the stream into a mode which allows the next fgetc() to work correctly". Otherwise it malfunctions like part 1 of your code. I guess that's about it

Comment: @AndyFaizan: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `fseek()` here - The C standard requires a positioning operation between a read and a write operation on an update stream, or between a write and a read. This is a positioning operation between a write and a read. It is not a no-op; it places the stream into a mode which allows the next `fgetc()` to work correctly, reliably, across platforms, as required by the C standard.

EDIT:

2 `fseek()` calls are required because the first one acts as the "no-op" call between an `fgetc()` and a subsequent `fputc()` call. After the `fputc()`, the second one acts as the "no-op" between the `fputc()` and the subsequent `fgetc()` call. (since a loop is running)

Comment: then why two fseek() are required

Comment: Try and remove the latter fseek() and check

Comment: I ckecked, it did nothing